# Loop through assotiave array from api platform

Tags: twig

After a json_decode from api platform I get this associative array :

```
array:5 [▼
  "@context" => "/api/contexts/Horaires"
  "@id" => "/api/horaires"
  "@type" => "hydra:Collection"
  "hydra:member" => array:55 [▼
    0 => array:13 [▼
      "@id" => "/api/horaires/1"
      "@type" => "Horaires"
      "id" => 1
      "date" => "2022-03-21T00:00:00+00:00"
      "hour" => "1970-01-01T09:00:00+00:00"
    ]
    1 => array:13 [▼
      "@id" => "/api/horaires/2"
      "@type" => "Horaires"
      "id" => 2
      "date" => "2022-03-22T00:00:00+00:00"
      "hour" => "1970-01-01T09:00:00+00:00"
    ]
    2 => array:13 [▶]
```

How do I get a list in twig with id, date, hour?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What is displayed above is the dump in twig. But I get only errors when I try several ways with loop on it, ie {{ horaires.id }} : "Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a string variable ("/api/contexts/Horaires".

Comment: Please post your attempts then as well

Comment: {% for horaire in horaires %}
                   {{ horaire.id }}
            {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are trying to access is not directly accessible in the variable `horaires` that you are passing but lives in the property `hydra:member`.

```
{% for horaire in data['hydra:member'] %}
    {{ horaire.id }}
    {{ horaire.date|date('d-m-Y') }} {{ horaire.hour|date('H:i:s') }}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/n1r8pv)

---

*sidenote*

As the property's name `hydra:member` is not really a "valid" property name, you can't access it with the `dot`-notation, e.g. `data.hydra:member`.
You would need to use the array notation to access it's value(s), e.g. `data['hydra:member']`

Comment: Tanks a lot! It would have been great if this what written more clearly in some documentation (symfony, twig or api-platform).